# SQL to fetch Data from 2 tables only using Join where we need empty records from second table as well

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

We have a situation in which one part of our stored procedure need to be filled with a ***join*** query, which had multiple filters in it. We need a solution only with join (it is easy to implement in the subquery, but our situation demands it to be a **join** [since the procedure has a where clause followed by it] )

We have two tables Customer and Order. We need to exclude the rows of Customer table, if Customer_id is present Order table & order_code = 10 & Customer.Grade = 3. It is not mandatory for all Customer_id to be present in Order table, but we still need it in the final result.

```
   Customer Table                             OrderTable
Customer_id     Grade                   Customer_id     order_code 
 1                3                            1            10
 2                3                            1            40                                
 3                2                            2            50                        
 4                3                            3            30
```

*Multiple Customer_id can be present in the OrderTable

Expected result :

```
Customer_id     Grade
    2            3    
    3            2        
    4            3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you need, not sure I understand the question properly.

`select c.id, c.grade 
from customer c left join customer_order o on (c.id = o.customer_id and o.order_code <> 10)
where c.grade = 3`

This should give you all customers with a Grade of 3 that also have orders, provided the order_code is not 10. If you want to show customers that do not have any orders also, make it a left join.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the logic like this:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not (grade = 3 and
           exists (select 1
                   from orders o
                   where o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                         o.order_code = 10
                  )
           );
```